# Rust Box vs pointer

Tags: rust

Reading the Rust documentation about `Box` it seems to work just like a normal pointer.
One example they give is this:

```rust
enum List {
    Cons(i32, Box<List>),
    Nil,
}

use crate::List::{Cons, Nil};

fn main() {
    let list = Cons(1, Box::new(Cons(2, Box::new(Cons(3, Box::new(Nil))))));
}
```

But one could also write this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum List<'a> {
    Cons(i32, &'a List<'a>),
    Nil,
}

use crate::List::{Cons, Nil};

fn main() {
    let list = Cons(1, &Cons(2, &Cons(3, &Nil)));

    println!("{:?}", list);
}
```

What are the compelling reasons to use `Box`?
Is it just for syntactic sugar?
Are there situations that we could/should only use `Box` instead of a pointer?
If `Box` works like a pointer should I prefer to use a `Box` instead of a pointer?
Why don't I need lifetimes when using a `Box`?

Comment: The `Box` version allows dynamic allocation of memory (on heap) at runtime. The memory for the list elements in the reference version has to be allocated (probably on stack) at compile time.

Comment: Both boxes and references are pointers. They have the same memory representation. The difference is that a box _owns_ the target, which is dynamically allocated on the heap, while a reference _borrows_ the target, which could be anywhere. (Your second example only works because of static promotion – otherwise you wouldn't be allowed to borrow the temporary values.)

Comment: Note also that it's not common to call `&x` a pointer - it's a _reference_ (or _borrow_). Term "pointer" is usually reserved for raw pointers, which is like, well, C pointers and therefore unsafe to use.

Comment: Another common use for `Box` is when you want to *own* a *dynamically sized type* (`T: ?Size`) such as `dyn Trait` or `[T]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the compelling reasons to use Box?

`Box` allows to move a value to be **heap** allocated. Otherwise, by default, it would be stack allocated.

Literally from the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) description:

> A pointer type for heap allocation.

> Is it just for syntactic sugar?

Not it is not, you can use raw pointers, but `Box` are subdue to rust borrowing rules.

> Are there situations that we could/should only use Box instead of a pointer?

If you want to use **safe** rust code, you will be using `Box` most of the time.

> If Box works like a pointer should I prefer to use a Box instead of a pointer?

As before, unless something specific is needed you will be using `Box`.

> Why don't I need lifetimes when using a Box?

You don't need if the object is owned, if it is a `&` reference for example you will need to add a lifetime annotation sometimes.
For example, if you somehow need a heap allocated reference to a dynamic trait:

```rust
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    data: Box<&'a dyn SomeTrait>
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, the data for the OP's second example is neither on the heap nor on the stack.

Comment: @SvenMarnach uhm, how so? In that case the original object should be located somewher right?

Comment: The code apparently borrows temporary values, which looks like it should be an error. However, due [rvalue static promotion](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.html), these values get promoted to static variables, so they live in whatever segment static data lives in on the target architecture (e.g. BSS or DATA for ELF binaries on Linux).

Comment: @SvenMarnach, oh, I wasn't aware of that. I thought it would be stack allocated by default. But ofc it doesn't makes sense since it is static. Thanks for the explanation!!

Comment: @Netwave There are other places in memory than the stack and heap. For example, the program's data section and `mmap`ed regions. But Sven is wrong - the data in the asker's second example is on the stack.